# How to check by default visible value in drop down in protractor tool?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a drop down box and I want to check that "x" value is displayed by default.

Comment: Can you add more details, perhaps a code sample?

Comment: I have a drop down on the web page (developed in Angular JS). This drop down has a list of values like (Please select, Test, Develop). I want to verify that when user land on web page this drop down displays "Please select" in it. I am finding the drop down by its id but not able to verify that "Please select" is displayed in it. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I am using Protractor tool for automation testing, hence looking for a solution that how can we do this in Protractor tool.

Comment: Got the solution by my own :) Here it is:        
'expect(element(by.id('<id of the drop down>')).$('option:checked').getText()).toEqual('<Your expected value>');'

Comment: you could just have edited your question ... :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below line of code will check the default selected value of the drop down:

```
 expect(element(by.id('<id of the drop down>')).$('option:checked').getText()).toEqual('<Your expected value>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a similar test for the protractor website. Please take a look at the following test:

```
    it('should have items under Protractor Setup', function() {
      expect(menu.dropdown('Protractor Setup').itemNames()).toEqual([
          'Setting Up Protractor',
          'Setting Up the Selenium Server',
          'Setting Up the Browser',
          'Choosing a Framework'
      ]);
    });
```

[source](https://github.com/andresdominguez/protractor/blob/addGeneratedWebsite/website/test/e2e/navigation_spec.js#L38)